# How do I make my Batch Code a command I can access anywhere?

Tags: batch-file, system32

Executable files like `findstr.exe` are placed in the `\system32` folder and can be accessed anywhere from the command prompt. However doing this with one of my batch files only works in certain CDs. How can I turn my bat file into a command on Windows 10?

Comment: The operating system uses a few different settings to determine where to find files when you don’t specify the full path.  One you might be interested in is the PATH environment variable. Folders listed there are searched whenever you type in a file name without a path. If your batch file exists in one of those folders it will be found. System32 is a special folder. Depending on if you are running a 32-bit or 64-Bit program your file may or may not be found due to folder virtualization. Don’t use system32 for your own files.

Comment: In addition to changing the path variable, consider making a context menu entry to "access it anywhere"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A scalable and simple way to make a batch script accessible like an implicit command**

1. Create a new folder on the system where you want the scripts to be
   accessible from "anywhere" from the command prompt, and then set
   this folder in the `PATH` environment variable (e.g.
   `C:\LinkScripts`).
2. Use [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to link the actual scripts in others locations, and create a symbolic file link
   to each script to the new folder you created and added to the `PATH`
   environment variable (see **How do I set or change the PATH system variable?**).
3. Open a new instance of command prompt once `PATH` adjustments are made and now when you type in the name of the script and press enter, it will run that batch file logic of the batch file(s) you linked with [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).

---

**Batch Examples**

```
md C:\LinkScripts
mklink C:\LinkScripts\test.cmd C:\Actual\Script\Folder\test.cmd
mklink C:\LinkScripts\pest.cmd C:\Colder\Script\Bolder\pest.cmd
mklink C:\LinkScripts\zest.cmd C:\Different\Script\Shoulder\zest.cmd
```

**Results**

Now you can open a new command prompt and run `zest`, `test` or `pest` with or without the appended `.cmd` (or `.bat`) file extension and it will run whatever logic is in each. This will allow you to easily be able to run a simple command for each or any newly added scripts which you need to use in this manner.

---

### Further Resources

- > ### [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)
  >
  > **Windows 10 and Windows 8**
  >
  > 1. In Search, search for and then select: **System** (Control Panel)
  > 2. Click the **Advanced system settings** link.
  > 3. Click **Environment Variables**. In the section **System Variables**, find
  >      the `PATH` environment variable and select it. Click **Edit**. If the `PATH`
  >      environment variable does not exist, click **New**.
  > 4. In the **Edit System Variable** (or **New System Variable**) window, specify
  >      the value of the PATH environment variable. Click **OK**. Close all
  >      remaining windows by clicking **OK**.
  > 5. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
  >
  > **Windows 7**
  >
  > 1. From the desktop, right click the **Computer** icon.
  > 2. Choose **Properties** from the context menu.
  > 3. Click the **Advanced system settings** link.
  > 4. Click **Environment Variables**. In the section **System Variables**, find
  >      the `PATH` environment variable and select it. Click **Edit**. If the `PATH`
  >      environment variable does not exist, click **New**.
  > 5. In the **Edit System Variable** (or **New System Variable**) window,
  >       specify the value of the `PATH` environment variable. Click **OK**. Close
  >       all remaining windows by clicking **OK**.
  > 6. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
  >
  > <sub>[source](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)</sub>
- [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

Comment: can I just put the actual file in the path folder instead of using MKlink?

Comment: @MarkDodsons I don't think that will work as the `PATH` environmental variable is for "paths" and not files but you could add the actual "path" the scripts reside in to the `PATH`, and then it should work just the same and not require the MKLink. The MKLink solution is just to help standardize and have the option to add any script in any folder to it and since it's already part of the `PATH` then the script file symlinks within that folder work as you need.